# Find the iteration in the for loop with the highest value in my code

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I try to list only the iteration with the highest value in my for loop code.

I created a helper code that can do this from a one-dimensional array. But I can't build it into my code.

This is my help code that I'm trying to insert into my code.

```
a=np.array([1,3,8,4,11,5,10,4,0])
maxv=a[0]
for i in a:
    if i > maxv:
        maxv=i
print(maxv)
```

In this part of the code, I tried to select the maximum value from all the iterations from for loop

```
for (j), (k) in zip(a,b):
    z1[:]=0
    z1[:j]=1#inserts as many values of 1 into the array, according to the iteration in varieble a
   # print(z1)
    z2[:]=0
    z2[:k]=1##inserts as many values of 1 into the array, according to the iteration in varieble a
    v=np.hstack((z1, z2))    
   # print(np.hstack((z1, z2)))
    if z1[1]==1 and z2[0]==1:
        pocet_jedx=np.count_nonzero(z1) #calculates the number of non-zero values
        pocet_jedy=np.count_nonzero(z2)
        print(pocet_jedy) #count non-zero value
```

I tried to comment on my code to make it easier to understand

my full code :

```
import os
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

x=np.arange(0,2) #create array [0,1,2]
y=np.arange(0,2)
z=np.arange(0,len(x)+len(y)) # 0,1,2,3 create array 
z[:]=0 # 0,0,0,0 insert zero in arrays

X=np.arange(0,3) #0,1,2
Y=np.arange(0,3) #0.1 2

#get combination of X, Y
mesh = np.array(np.meshgrid(X, Y))
combinations = mesh.T.reshape(-1, 2)
sums = combinations.sum(axis=1)#calculates the values in each row

t=np.hsplit(combinations,2) #split array 
a=t[0]#save the first column in the variable a
a=np.transpose(a) 
b=t[1] ##save the second column in the variable a
b=np.transpose(b)
a=a[-1] #remove excess parentheses
b=b[-1] #remove excess parentheses
#print(a,b)#arrays a and b determine how many 1 and 0 should be in each iteration
z12=np.hsplit(z,2) # split arrays
z1=z12[0]
z2=z12[1]

for (j), (k) in zip(a,b):
    z1[:]=0
    z1[:j]=1#inserts as many values of 1 into the array, according to the iteration in varieble a
   # print(z1)
    z2[:]=0
    z2[:k]=1##inserts as many values of 1 into the array, according to the iteration in varieble a
    v=np.hstack((z1, z2))    
   # print(np.hstack((z1, z2)))
    if z1[1]==1 and z2[0]==1:
        pocet_jedx=np.count_nonzero(z1) #calculates the number of non-zero values
        pocet_jedy=np.count_nonzero(z2)
        print(pocet_jedy) #count non-zero value
```

output:

```
1
2
```

I only need the highest value, in this case the value 2

As I say, the problem for me is to correctly insert the correct condition
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please note that your first loop can be entirely replaced by `maxv = max(a)`.

Comment: I know. I did so in my code I need to pull the highest value from the loop

Comment: Are you just trying to get the highest value of `pocet_jedy`?

Comment: I try to get a higher value from the variable pocet_jedy